# How to load a chunk on a specific page in Next.js

Tags: performance, webpack, next.js, three.js

[image]

In my upcoming project, I am utilizing the three.js package to incorporate a 3D model. However, due to the extensive size of the bundle, I opted to use webpack to divide it in my next.config file. Specifically, I used the cacheGroups function to create a new chunk, called three-js-chunk, that includes the three.js package. Although this approach has been successful in reducing the size of the main chunk, I have encountered a new issue. The three-js-chunk is loaded on every page, whereas I only require it on a specific page ( for ecample: /carmodel ) . Can you advise me on how to resolve this matter?

```
.
.
.
const nextConfig = {
    webpack: (config) => {
        config.optimization.splitChunks.cacheGroups = {
            ...config.optimization.splitChunks.cacheGroups,
            threeJsChunk: {
                chunks: "all",
                name: "three-js-chunk",
                test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]three[\\/]/,
            },
        }

        return config
    },
}
.
.
.
```